# Testing with selenium using Firefox can't find server

Tags: symfony, selenium, firefox, behat

I want to perform some BDD testing. Problem is that I can't get Firefox to work under Selenium 2. I am using Behat with Symfony 3 and I didn't find any problem with implementation and setting up whole environment. I used composer to install all dependencies and I didn't had any problem.

Since I am using vagrant with CentOS I installed all required packages. I even tried with older Firefox version but I didn't had any luck.

Problem is with Firefox. Every time I run test I got Firefox error:

```
Server not found
```

[image: Firefox response]

But when I ping  from command line I got response that server is working. Also when I navigate through website (same server) using browser all route are working fine.
[image: Ping response]

I really don't have any clue how to fix this issue. I tried to search problem on Internet but I didn't had any luck.

Command I used to run selenium server:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom switch
```

Behat config file:

```
#uncomment next lines to disable cache for gherkin
    #gherkin:
        #cache: false
    #autoload: %paths.base%/tests/Functional/AdminBundle/Behat/Bootstrap/Context
    #autoload: %paths.base%/tests/features/bootstrap
    autoload: %paths.base%/tests/Functional/Features/Bootstrap
    formatters:
        progress: ~
    suites:
        admin:
            paths:
                - %paths.base%//tests/Functional/Features/Admin
            contexts:
                - Tests\Functional\Features\Bootstrap\AdminContext
        front:
            paths:
                - %paths.base%//tests/Functional/Features/Front
            contexts:
                - Tests\Functional\Features\Bootstrap\AdminContext
        first:
          mink_session: default
          mink_javascript_session: selenium2
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Bex\Behat\ScreenshotExtension:
              image_drivers:
                local:
                  screenshot_directory: /var/www/symfony/tests/Screenshots
                  clear_screenshot_directory: true  # Enable removing all images before each test run. It is false by default.
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            sessions:
                default:
                    goutte: ~
                selenium2:
                    selenium2:
                        wd_host: 127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
            #default_session: snc_redis.session.handler
            #selenium2:
             #   wd_host: 127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
            #base_url: '%url.busrent_main_assets.base%'
            #javascript_session: selenium2
            browser_name: firefox
```

Comment: What is your firefox version ? You can check the compability between versions here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG

Comment: I tried with latest firefox and with 46.0 version and none of them worked